# Machine learning challenge: learn english pronunciation

Tags: machine-learning, phonetics

Say you want to take [CMU's phonetic data set](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict) input that looks like this:

```
ABERRATION  AE2 B ER0 EY1 SH AH0 N
ABERRATIONAL  AE2 B ER0 EY1 SH AH0 N AH0 L
ABERRATIONS  AE2 B ER0 EY1 SH AH0 N Z
ABERT  AE1 B ER0 T
ABET  AH0 B EH1 T
ABETTED  AH0 B EH1 T IH0 D
ABETTING  AH0 B EH1 T IH0 NG
ABEX  EY1 B EH0 K S
ABEYANCE  AH0 B EY1 AH0 N S
```

(The word is to the left, to the right are a series of phonemes, [key here](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict#about))

And you want to use it as training data for a machine learning system that would take new words and guess how they would be pronounced in English.

It's not so obvious to me at least because there isn't a fixed token size of letters which could possible map to a phoneme. I have a feeling that something to do with a markov chain might be the right way to go.

How would you do this?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that both the CMU and moby data are for American pronunciation and don't have a very good set of phonemes for British or other English varieties. In fact even the CMU and moby data have different sets of phonemes. The moby pronunciator is here: http://icon.shef.ac.uk/Moby/mpron.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is called Grapheme-to-phoneme conversion, a subproblem of [Natural Language Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing). Google [brings up](http://www.google.com/search?q=grapheme+to+phoneme) a few papers.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely my field, but maybe build a neural network with several layers - earlier layers to guess the splitting of the words into sequential syllables, the later layers to guess the pronounciation of the said syllables.

Setting up a ANFIS-learning neural network is fairly straightforward for numerical data, for literal/phonetic data the task is undoubtedly several orders more complex.

Comment: can you really have an NN with a variable number of output nodes?

Comment: I believe so - quick googling suggests it is easier to train the networks separately and then combine to achieve several outputs.

This problem is far from trivial, and I don't claim to being able to really solve it.

Comment: Would you really need a variable number of output nodes?  Unless the number of phonemes is prohibitively large, just have as many output nodes as possible phonemes.